# Несоответствие модулей opencart 2.2

Tags: opencart

Установил модуль категорий от Nikita_sp, теперь когда пытаюсь добавить товар выкидывает из админки
Выдает такую ошибку

```
2016-09-01 18:19:26 - PHP Notice:  Error: Could not load template /home/g/site/site.ru/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/default/template/module/category_menu.tpl! in /home/g/site/site.ru/public_html/system/storage/modification/system/library/template/basic.php on line 26
2016-09-01 18:19:28 - PHP Notice:  Error: Could not load template /home/g/site/site.ru/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/default/template/module/category_menu.tpl! in /home/g/site/site.ru/public_html/system/storage/modification/system/library/template/basic.php on line 26
2016-09-01 18:19:30 - PHP Notice:  Error: Could not load template /home/g/site/site.ru/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/default/template/module/category_menu.tpl! in /home/g/site/site.ru/public_html/system/storage/modification/system/library/template/basic.php on line 26
2016-09-01 18:19:39 - PHP Notice:  Error: Could not load template /home/g/site/site.ru/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/default/template/module/category_menu.tpl! in /home/g/site/site.ru/public_html/system/storage/modification/system/library/template/basic.php on line 26
```

Что нужно сделать? вот немогу понять, я вроде когда его устанавливал поменял пару файлов, чтобы он нормально отображался.

Сам код модуля из контроллера

```
class ControllerModuleCategoryMenu extends Controller {
private $cache_data = null;

public function index($settings) {
$this->cache_data = $this->cache->get('category_menu');
if (!$this->cache_data) {
$this->cache_data = array();
}

if($settings['style'] == 1){
$tpl_name = "category_menu";
$this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/category_menu.js');
}else{
$tpl_name = "category_menu_vertical";
}

if (file_exists('catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/'.$tpl_name.'.css')) {
$this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/stylesheet/'.$tpl_name.'.css');
} else {
$this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/'.$tpl_name.'.css');
}


$this->language->load('module/category_menu');
$this->load->model('tool/image');

$data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

$this->load->model('catalog/category');
$this->load->model('catalog/product');

$data['categories'] = array();

$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
if($settings['category_count'] == 1){
if (!isset($this->cache_data['count'][$category['category_id']])) {
$total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts(array('filter_category_id' => $category['category_id'], 'filter_sub_category' => true));
$this->cache_data['count'][$category['category_id']] = $total;
}else{
$total = $this->cache_data['count'][$category['category_id']];
}
}

$children_data = array();
if( $settings['level'] > 1){
$children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);
foreach ($children as $child) {

if($settings['child_count'] == 1){
if (!isset($this->cache_data['count'][$child['category_id']])) {
$data = array(
'filter_category_id' => $child['category_id'],
'filter_sub_category' => true
);
$product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);
$this->cache_data['count'][$child['category_id']] = $product_total;
}else{
$product_total = $this->cache_data['count'][$child['category_id']];
}
}


$subchildren_data = array();
if($settings['level'] > 2){
$subchildren = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);
foreach ($subchildren as $subchild) {

if($settings['subchild_count'] == 1){
if (!isset($this->cache_data['count'][$subchild['category_id']])) {
$subdata = array(
'filter_category_id' => $subchild['category_id'],
'filter_sub_category' => true
);
$subproduct_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($subdata);
$this->cache_data['count'][$subchild['category_id']] = $subproduct_total;
}else{
$subproduct_total = $this->cache_data['count'][$subchild['category_id']];
}
}

$subchildren_data[] = array(
'category_id' => $subchild['category_id'],
'name' => $subchild['name'] . ($settings['subchild_count'] ? ' (' . $subproduct_total . ')' : ''),
'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'] . '_' . $subchild['category_id']),
'image' => ($settings['subchild_images']['status'] ? $this->model_tool_image->resize($subchild['image'], $settings['subchild_images']['width'], $settings['subchild_images']['height']) : false)
);
}
}

$children_data[] = array(
'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
'name' => $child['name'] . ($settings['child_count'] ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']),
'image' => ($settings['child_images']['status'] ? $this->model_tool_image->resize($child['image'], $settings['child_images']['width'], $settings['child_images']['height']) : false),
'subchildren' => $subchildren_data,
'column' => $child['column'] ? $child['column'] : 1,
);
}
}

$data['categories'][] = array(
'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
'name' => $category['name'] . ($settings['category_count'] ? ' (' . $total . ')' : ''),
'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id']),
'image' => ($settings['category_images']['status'] ? $this->model_tool_image->resize($category['image'], $settings['category_images']['width'], $settings['category_images']['height']) : false),
'children' => $children_data,
'column' => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
);
}

if($this->cache_data){
$this->cache->set('category_menu', $this->cache_data);
}

if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/'.$tpl_name.'.tpl')) {
return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template').'/template/module/'.$tpl_name.'.tpl', $data);
} else {
return $this->load->view('module/category_menu_vertical', $data);
}
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Так прочитайте ошибку. Говорит `category_menu.tpl` шаблона под этот модуль у вас нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/home/g/site/site.ru/public_html/catalog/view/theme/**default/template**/default/template/module/category_menu.tpl

В тех файлах которые менял, внимательно проверь пути, во время подключения не может найти шаблон из-за того, что путь "задвоился".